# Angular - implementing different interface languages

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm unsure of what the best practices are for implementing different languages for the interface of an Angular site. In a quick fix, I stuck it in a controller like so:

```
if($rootScope.interfaceText == null){
    $http({
            url: '/interface.php',
            method: "GET"
         }).success(function(json, status){
            $rootScope.interfaceText = json; 
         }).error(function(status, response) {
            console.log('error status',status);
            console.log('errot response',response);
         });
}
```

The controller obviously has root scope injected. This obviously isn't the best wayto go about it. Whenever I have a directive with an  isolate scope, it requires that I bind the variable interfaceText to the parent. This makes for poor organization. I would put it into a service, but wouldn't I then need to write watchers for every controller? Or could I simply write

```
$scope.interfaceText = interfaceTextService;
```

in every controller?

Comment: I advise you to use angular-translate by Pascal Precht

Comment: @FrankvanWijk good call. Not sure how to accepts this as the answer.

Comment: I will create an answer so that other people are helped with it too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying is some manual piece of code that handles translations for you. First of all, you don't need `$rootScope`. `$rootScope` is necessary in a very small number of cases, since `$scope` - which is a child node of `$rootScope` - can be injected anywhere.

Second, the Angular module `angular-translate` by Pascal Precht solves all of the translation stuff in Angular. This is a very mature module created when Angular was just becoming populair.

This particular problem is described in this chapter: https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/12_asynchronous-loading

Als translations are automatically displayed using a filter or directive.

### Filter

```
<p>{{ 'title' | translate }}</p>
```

### Directive

```
<p translate="title"></p>
```